# Java SQL statement cannot find symbol

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I am trying to create a table in sqlite3 using java and I created the following procedure. I get the following error.

> ```
> Zoo.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
>       Statement st = null;
>       ^
>   symbol:   class Statement
>   location: class Zoo
> 1 error
> ```

```
 //creates the table
    public void creaTaulaCategories() throws SQLException {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE CATEGORIES(" +
                         "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                         "nom VARCHAR(40))";
        Statement st = null;
        try{
                st = conn.createStatement();
                st.executeUpdate(sql);
        }finally{
                if (st != null) {
                        st.close();
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you import java.sql.Statement?

Comment: @khelwood Is it an import? I am using three SQL imports. Maybe it is, I am going to try.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! @khelwood

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement; //Missing import ;(
public class Zoo{
    private static final String NOM_BASE_DE_DADES = "animals.bd";
    private static final String CADENA_DE_CONNEXIO = "jdbc:sqlite:" +
                                                     NOM_BASE_DE_DADES;
    private Connection conn = null;

    public void connecta() throws SQLException {
        if (conn != null) return;
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CADENA_DE_CONNEXIO);
    }

    public void desconnecta() throws SQLException {
        if (conn == null) return;
        conn.close();
    }
    //creates the table
    public void creaTaulaCategories() throws SQLException {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE CATEGORIES(" +
                         "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                         "nom VARCHAR(40))";
        Statement st = null;
        try{
                st = conn.createStatement();
                st.executeUpdate(sql);
        }finally{
                if (st != null) {
                        st.close();
                }
        }
    }
}
```